# How ti fix the "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." issue in Azure web app services?

Tags: spring-mvc, jenkins, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have a simple web app which if I deploy to Azure through Intelij (Using Azure App plugin ) the app works perfectly. But when I tried deploying using Jenkins the log says deployment successful , but when I try to navigate to the site it says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." Am I missing anything ?

As per my understanding as My project is working fine when deployed using Intelij, but not working through Jenkins, so the problem will be in my Jenkins Job. Here is the configuration I am  using :
 Publish Files
 Files  :target\spring-mvc-example.war
 Source Directory(optional):target
 Target Directory(optional): webapps

Answer (score 0):

Could you please restart the website and check once.

For testing/debugging purposes you can turn on the Azure detailed messaging, and turn back off when its ready for production. To do so, you have to follow these two steps,

Login to Azure > App Services (left side menu) > Your Web App > Diagnostics logs (search box is at the top if you can't find it), then turn on Detailed Error Messages or turn on all of the logging options, up to you. Now add the following in your Web Config file, In your Web Config file add BEFORE system.web closing tag, . Similarly, add BEFORE . Finally, upload the Web Config to Azure and cross your fingers. If you follow the steps correctly, that will show the error messages in detail and hopefully from there

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to fix the problem though..:) The mistake I was doing was  while creating the App service plan for the web app, I was selecting Pricing Tier as Standard. Which actually does not unzip the war file automatically. So I changed the  App service plan to set the pricing tier to Premium and this time the war got unpacked and the site started working fine.